# Fastest way to find all cycles in a big directed graph

Tags: java, performance, graph

I have to find all the cycles in a directed graph where every node has to only go out to 1 node but it can have more than one come in towards it and print all the nodes that are in a cycle.

Is there anyway I can make [my code][1] run faster?

right now it runs 100k nodes at about 4s but the time-limit is 1.5s

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        long startTime = 0;
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

        int numOfPeople = Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        StringTokenizer following = new StringTokenizer(input.readLine(), " ");
        startTime = System.nanoTime();

        int[] people = new int[numOfPeople],               // index -> personID, value -> personID's friend
                winningPotentials = new int[numOfPeople];  // index -> personID, value -> personID's winningPotential
        Arrays.fill(winningPotentials, 50);

        // adding followings of people
        for (int i = 0 ; i < numOfPeople ; i++) {
            people[i] = Integer.parseInt(following.nextToken()) - 1;
        }

        /*
                SETTING WINNER POTENTIALS
         */
        int numOfWinners = 0;
        for (int person : people) {
            if (winningPotentials[person] == 50) {
                Deque<Integer> path = new ArrayDeque<>();
                path.addLast(person);

                while (true) {
                    int friend = people[person];

                    if (path.contains(friend)) {
                        // all those in a friend group are winningPot = 100
                        while (path.getLast() != friend) {
                            if (winningPotentials[path.peekLast()] != 100) {
                                numOfWinners++;
                                winningPotentials[path.peekLast()] = 100;
                            }
                            path.removeLast();
                        }
                        if (winningPotentials[path.peekLast()] != 100) {
                            numOfWinners++;
                            winningPotentials[path.peekLast()] = 100;
                        }
                        path.removeLast();

                        break;
                    }
                    // if friend hasn't been checked before, repeat
                    else {
                        path.addLast(friend);
                        person = friend;
                    }
                }
                // anyone in the path that wasnt in a friend group is winnerPot=0
                for (int person2 : path)
                    winningPotentials[person2] = 0;
            }
        }

        /*
                PRINTING THE RESULTS
        */
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(numOfWinners + "\n");

        // print each winner
        for (int i = 0 ; i < winningPotentials.length ; i++)
            if (winningPotentials[i] == 100)
                sb.append((i + 1) + " ");
        sb.append("\nExecution Time ->\t" + ((System.nanoTime() - startTime) / 1000000) + "ms");
        output.write(sb.toString());
        output.flush();
        output.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a BufferedWriter ? Can you just not do a `System.out.println(sb.toString())` ?

Comment: I don't really know why but it was way slower

Answer (score 0):

This can be implemented as a modified BFS algorithm.

Difference is what whenever you see a point that has already been added to the queue, and isn't the point before the one you were just at, you have found a cycle. So when you add points to the queue you add the current path to that point instead of just the point, but you also add the adjacent point (the last on the path) to a list of already found points.

I would probably wait to calculate the winning Potentials until you have found all the cycles.